# NSExpression's expressionValueWithObject:context: with non-nil parameters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsexpression

Every example of `expressionValueWithObject:context:` that have seen so far, even in the Apple docs, always pass nil for bot parameters.

Anybody could explain what these are for and a real life example?

Thanks in advance!